# How we can store the User utterance in a parameter without using @sys.any within the Dialogflow cx

Tags: parameters, dialogflow-es

In Dialogflow cx I created one page for Open question like "How Can I help you today...?"
Once End-user says anything (Example:  I need to reset my password), I need to store that entire utterance into a parameter without using @sys.any entity.

I need to store that entire utterance into a parameter without using @sys.any entity.

Answer (score 0):

You can capture and store the entire user utterance without using the @sys.any entity by creating a custom parameter and configuring a fulfillment to extract the user's input.

**Create a Parameter:**

In your CX agent, navigate to the appropriate location where you want to capture the user's input (e.g., a page for open questions). Create a custom parameter to store the user's input. Let's call it user_utterance:

Parameter Name: user_utterance
Entity Type: None (leave it empty) 
Is List: No

**Add a Transition from User Input:**

In the same location (page) where you're capturing the open question, add a transition from user input to a new page. This page will be used for fulfillment.

**Set Up Fulfillment:**

On the fulfillment page, you can use a webhook to capture the user's input and store it in the user_utterance parameter. You can write custom fulfillment code in your preferred language (e.g., JavaScript, Python) to extract and store the user's input.

**Transition Back to the Original Page:**

After storing the user's input, you can add a transition back to the original page where you asked the open question.